AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__' - troubleshooting retinaface with tensorflow
I am having technical difficulties in installing retinaface and tensorflow.
I have the most current version of tensorflow (to my knowledge). However, I am under the impression that there is a tensorflow 2.5 that I am unable to install..
I installed retinaface manually and I am getting a tf error...
line 13, in <module>
    tf_version = int(tf.__version__.split(".", maxsplit=1)[0])
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'

I can't say I was expecting a flawless install as I always seem to have issues with tf.
pip install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.5
conda install tensorflow

I currently have tensorflow-cpu 2.16 alongside tensorflow 2.16
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Hi @Sean Tishenor , It seems you're encountering some issues with TensorFlow installation and version compatibility. The error message AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__' suggests that TensorFlow might not be installed properly or that the version you're using isn't what you anticipated. Here's how you can resolve it by installing the correct TensorFlow version,

Run the following command to check which versions of TensorFlow you have installed pip uninstall tensorflow tensorflow-cpu If you want to install TensorFlow 2.5 specifically, you can do so with pip install tensorflow==2.5
